# Adding a transition to two classes on toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I am working on the below demo. Why am I not able to add `transition` to each of `.fa-chevron-right` or `.fa-chevron-left` on toggling two classes?

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
  $('.fa').toggleClass('fa-chevron-right fa-chevron-down');
});
```

```css
body{padding:30px;}
button{padding:12px; min-width:60px;}
.fa-chevron-down{
  transition: all 3s ease;
}
.fa-chevron-right{
  transition: all 3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn btn-default">  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS transition is for changing CSS properties (think `background-color` or `width`). Your css class is simply changing the image that's rendered, not actually changing any css styles. CSS `transition` would work if you used something like `transform: rotate(0.25turn);` instead of two different images.

```js
$("button").on("click", function(){
  $('.fa').toggleClass('css-chevron-right css-chevron-down');
});
```

```css
body{padding:30px;}
button{padding:12px; min-width:60px;}
.css-chevron-down{
  transform: rotate(0.25turn);
  transition: all 3s ease;
}
.css-chevron-right{
  transition: all 3s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button class="btn btn-default">  <i class="fa fa-chevron-right css-chevron-right pull-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```